# Value for the parameter: func(Pick<Module, "id">[])

Tags: angular, typescript, parameter-passing, ngrx, facade

I have a function like the following

```
getModuleMeasures(
modules: Pick<Module, "id">[]
){
return this.store$.select(getModuleMeasures(modules));
}
```

I don't know what type of value that needs to be passed as an argument.

I tried passing the module id's as the parameter but it is not accepting. when i try to pass the id as string throws **Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Module, "id">'.** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter needs to be an array of objects, which will have one key, `id`. The type of the value of `id` will be whatever it is in `Module`

```
type Module = {
  id: string, 
  abc: number
}
function getModuleMeasures(modules: Pick<Module, "id">[]) {
  console.log(modules)
}

getModuleMeasures([{id:'123'}])
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwK4BtoF4oG8BQUoCWCAXFAM7ABOBAdgOYA0UeUAhgEYDGpNSAtuwiUcAXxwAzJDU7ACcGlDoRg8ZGhgRWZJJQhkAFH0So9pAAoFOAawA8qk0wBERRwD4A2gF0AlNhad5Mjg0ADoUODpDYzQyb1EcHCUVaIgNLR09fXcsImIAcgBGACYAZjyRHyA)